# Ubuntu not using discrete GPU as primary graphics

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, x-server, gpu

My laptop will not run the graphics trough my discrete GPU, only the integrated one. I've tried a few things to correct that but so far without success. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.02LT.

**Specs:**

I own a DELL 15 XPS9570, which comes with an Intel i7-8750H with integrated graphics, and a GTX1050Ti Mobile.

**Stuff I've tried:**

```
$ sudo lshw -C display
*-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:146 memory:ec000000-ecffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ed000000-ed07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:143 memory:eb000000-ebffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I've purged and reinstalled the most up-to-date driver using:

```
$ sudo apt purge 
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430
```

Checking that the version of the driver I have is the actual one installed...

```
$ nvidia-smi
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.14       Driver Version: 430.14       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 105...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   37C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /  4042MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then I read about this prime tool that I could use to switch which graphics processor my computer use called prime.

I tried installing PRIME - a tool with which aparently you can switch from GPU to integrated graphics cards and vice-versa...

Before I installed Prime I purged bumblebee which apparently can't work concomitantly with Prime:

```
$sudo apt-get purge bumblebee
```

but ...

Package 'bumblebee' is not installed, so not removed
So I installed Prime, and the current version installed of Prime:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-prime
$ dpkg -l nvidia-prime

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name               Version        Architecture   Description
+++-==================-==============-==============-==========================================
ii  nvidia-prime       0.8.8.2        all            Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
```

I also tried installing the prime-indicator-plus tool:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install prime-indicator-plus
$ sudo reboot
```

The prime-indicator-plus-thing did not work. The nvidia tool does not show up in my bar... But whatever.

I can do:

```
$ sudo prime-select nvidia
Info: selecting the nvidia profile
```

List item

but then if I type in the dash "about", and go to "details" it shows Graphics Intel UHD graphics 630.

Then I read I could do it manualy on the Nvidia X-server window. Well, I open the Nvidia X-Server thing.

When I open Nvidia X-Server this thing shows up. Or better, it does not showup...

[image: X-server being a nasty]

x-server looks bugged....

in fact when I do:

```
$sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg : Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.2-2)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Now I'm stuck. I don't know how to fix this. Or even if this X-server thing has any correlation with my problem.

PS: On my other hard drive which has windows my discrete GPU it runs Dotes 1440p on max settings at almost 70fps. Its beautiful...

Comment: did you try to just reinstall ubuntu.
i have the same problem + atom doesn't work without discrete gpu so I'll try to reinstall ubuntu.